# Function to change TextView doesn't work when called from another class

Tags: java, android

I've written a function to change the text of a `TextView`. It's in the class of the activity which contains the `TextView`. However, this function doesn't work when it's called from another class.

The function looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public void changeTest() {
        TextView test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTest);
        guessedLetters.setText("test");
    }
}
```

If I call this function from my `MainActivity`, it works perfectly fine:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gameplay);

        changeTest();
    }
}
```

But if I call it from a class that extends MainActivity, I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1884)`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gameplay);

        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.myFunction();
    }
}

public class MyClass extends MainActivity {
    public void myFunction() {
        MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
        mainActivity.changeTest();
    }
}
```

How could I fix this?

Comment: It works when in onCreate you have called setContentView but have you called it by the other way? can you post at least that line on both onCreate methods?

Comment: I've updated the code, hopefully it's clearer now :-)

Comment: @Algorithm_NL I posted some code that you can try to replicate

Comment: In **MyClass** you dont need to create **object of MainActivity** in that method just write **this.changeTest()**, I think it will change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this result using another activity extending from MainActivity, you can do it in this way:

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //changeTest(this);

       AnotherActivity a = new AnotherActivity();
        a.updateTest(this);


    }

    public void changeTest(Activity activity) {
        TextView test = (TextView)activity.findViewById(R.id.textViewTest);
        test.setText("test");
    }
}
```

**AnotherActivity**

```
public class AnotherActivity extends MainActivity {

   public void updateTest(Activity activity){
       changeTest(activity);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this did the trick! However, I'm now having the same problem when defining a new Intent (instead of defining a TextView) with `Intent intent = new Intent(this, GameplayActivity.class);`. Where should I add 'activity' there?

Comment: where are you defining this intent? inside the method changeTest()?

Answer (score 1):

Might this help you.

***MainActivity***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static TextView tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    OtherClass otherClass = new OtherClass();
    otherClass.setText("TEST");
    }
}
```

***Other Class***

```
public class OtherClass {
    public void setText(String txt){
       MainActivity.tv.setText(txt);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gameplay);

        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.myFunction(this);
    }
}

public class MyClass extends MainActivity {
    public void myFunction(MainActivity mainActivity) {
        mainActivity.changeTest();
    }
}
```